# Getting incorrect output which is i am having an issue in getting the sum of two different lists

Tags: python

I am not getting the sum of the given input list and the generated list in the code the user input gets red multiple times

```
text = input("enter the ciphertext: ")

for char in text:
    print(char,(ord(char)))

for char in text:
    test_list = text # printing original list

print("The original list : " + str(test_list)) 

# Convert String list to ascii values 
# using loop + ord() 
res = [] 
for ele in test_list: 
    res.extend(ord(num) for num in ele) 

#printing result 
#print(res)
#print("Maximum element in the list is :", +(min(res)))

a = []
n = int(input('enter the size key: '))
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input('enter the key elements: ')))

for element in a:
    for char in text:
        q=((ord(char))+element)
        z = chr(q)
        print(ord(char),element,q,z)
```

Please help me with this problem if any one takes this request thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is probably where your issue stems from:

```py
for char in text:
    test_list = text # printing original list
```

In that block you are setting the value of `test_list` to `text`. So each iteration in the loop sets the value of `text_list` to the same value. You either don't need the loop and you can just set `test_list` to `text` directly if you want them to be equal. Or you need to modify your loop to set the values of `text_list` to the correct values you want.

Comment: i want the corresponding ascii values of a,b,c to be read in the output i am getting only the c value can u pls help me with that [link](https://imgur.com/a/UsW7jPb)